# How to get the list of webelement using WebDriver

Tags: selenium

i want to get the list of element in a list, so the html page is:

```
<div class="list">  

 </h2>Select Item
    <ul>

    <li>
        <h4>

            Item

        </h4>
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="summary1"></li>
            <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="summary2"></li>
            <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="summary3"></li>
            <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="summary4"></li>


     </li>
     <li>

    <h4>

        Chaine

    </h4>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="graph1"></li>
        <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="graph2"></li>
        <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="graph3"></li>
        <li class="component-panel-item" data-cpn="graph4"></li>

    </ul>


</div>
```

So here i want to get the list of all Item and Chaine.
The list should be like : Item list is = summary1, summary2..
                          Chaine list is = graph1, graph2,..

How can do this using webdriver?
Thank you

Comment: What language do you use? Have you tried anything by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `findElements()`:

```
List<WebElement> summaries = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[data-cpn^='summary']"));
List<WebElement> graphs = driver.findElemetns(By.cssSelector("[data-cpn^='graph']"));
```

Comment: I use java and tried this Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/select")));
    int i =select.getList();
    System.out.print("number of options ="+i); but it's not working